# Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'double'

Tags: c#, void

Wrote a method which returns the inch equivalent of its centimeter argument but it says cannot implicitly convert type void to double.

How do i correct this?

Heres the code:

```
     private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Double inches = InchEquivalent(10.5);
    }

    public void InchEquivalent(double centimeters)
    {
        double answer;
        answer = centimeters * 0.394;
        MessageBox.Show(answer.ToString());

        return;
    }
```

Comment: Take some time to read through this tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114.aspx

Comment: You need to make `InchEquivalent` *return* `double`, right now it is specified to return `void`.

Comment: `InchEquivalent` does not return anything.

Comment: You may want to brush up on programming fundamentals as a whole.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa716286%28v=vs.60%29.aspx
https://www.coursera.org/course/programming1

Answer (score 2):

As the guys in the comments tried to tell you, you have to give the function a return type like this:

```
public double InchEquivalent(double centimeters)
{
    var answer = centimeters * 0.394;
    MessageBox.Show(answer.ToString());

    return answer;
}
```

Mind the `double` instead of the `void` in `public double InchEquivalent` and the `return answer;` instead of just `return;`

But I would recommend keeping the function **pure** and responsible for only one thing (that is don't do the `MessageBox.Show` in there (I guess it's only for debugging anyway), and you can make it static if you like:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var inches = Centimeters2Inches(10.5);
    MessageBox.Show(inches.ToString());
}

public static double Centimeters2Inches(double centimeters)
{
    return centimeters * 0.394;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, you've got a function that does units conversion.  The units conversion input centimeters and outputs inches.  Very good.

The input is done via a function parameter.  Excellent choice.

The output is done using a `MessageBox` to show it to the user.  This may work for quick testing and throwaway code, but it's not a good approach in the long run.  There are basically two problems:

1. It isn't reusable.  Now you want to use the output in some way, but you can't, because it isn't returned.
2. It violates the Single Responsibility Principle.  The format of the string shown to the user is part of the conversion.  There's no way for the caller to add some explanatory text to the message box.  Or to specify that it should appear in a textbox instead of a messagebox.

A better design would be for the conversion to output the value in inches as a return value, and let some other code take care of the presentation.